# Troubles implementing LIMMA for paired samples (before/after treatment) comparaisons

Tags: gene-expression, limma

i try to implement LIMMA for paired samples in order to compare gene expression before/after treatment. But...i'm not confident in my results since every single gene expression seems to be significantly associeted with the treatment!

Here is my methodology:

`mat<-t(df)`

where df is a dataframe with:
-1000 columns for different gene expression
-+ 1 column 'id' (10 different id, repeated 2 times)
-+ 1 column 'ttt' (0=before, 1=after treatment)
-20 rows of observations (10 patients observed twice)

So once I get my matrix:

`subject_id<-df$id` A vector with 10 different id repeated 2 times

`ttt<-as.factor(df$ttt)` A vector with the treatment status (before/after)

Here is my design matrix:

`design<-model.matrix(~ 0+ttt)`

`colnames(design) <- levels(ttt)`

As asked in limma() description i specify the correlations:

`corfit <- duplicateCorrelation(mat,design,block=subject_id)`

Fiting of the model:

`fit<-lmFit(mat,design,block =subject_id,correlation = corfit$consensus)`

`fit2<-eBayes(fit)`

Getting adjusted pvalues for every gene comparison before/after treatment:

`topTable(fit2, adjust.method='BH',number=1000)`

But every single gene expression seems to be relevant, so i'm very doubtful about my methodology
Any idea?
Many thanks!

Comment: what do you actually have, RNAseq or microarray data? I suspect you have RNAseq data and you need to normalize it

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. I have transcriptomic responses, with logarithmic transformation (one value per gene expression).

Comment: What u have above should be ok. Just note that for the last step u are testing all coefficients to be zero. Not sure if that is what u want

Comment: But if you specify treatment and groups correctly. It should be ok. Without more info, hard to tell